# Copy Hook Handler only recognizes folder operation instead of file operation in a directory

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried to create a copy hook handler that will recognize a file operation in a directory based on the code provided by Windows [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtCopyHookHandler-120e71c8) using the function [ICopyHook::CopyCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, but the odd thing is that it only recognizes the operation only for folder instead of file inside the folder. Here is my code:

```
#pragma region ICopyHook

IFACEMETHODIMP_(UINT) FolderCopyHook::CopyCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT wFunc, 
    UINT wFlags, LPCWSTR pszSrcFile, DWORD dwSrcAttribs, LPCWSTR pszDestFile, 
    DWORD dwDestAttribs)
{
    int result = IDYES;

    // If the file name contains "Test" and it is being renamed...
    if (wcsstr(pszSrcFile, L"Test") != NULL && wFunc == FO_RENAME)
    {
        wchar_t szMessage[256];
        StringCchPrintf(szMessage, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage), 
            L"Are you sure to rename the folder %s as %s ?", 
            pszSrcFile, pszDestFile);

        result = MessageBox(hwnd, szMessage, L"CppShellExtCopyHookHandler", 
            MB_YESNOCANCEL);
    }

//Theoritically it should filter all pszSrcFile variables that contains the directory that I want to monitor, including the file contained inside the directory, such as C:\\Users\\User\\CloudRAID\\test.txt but it does not work. 
     if (wcsstr(pszSrcFile, L"C:\\Users\\User\\CloudRAID") != NULL && wFunc == FO_COPY)
    {
        result = MessageBox(hwnd, L"Copy is detected at cloudraid home folder", L"CppShellExtCopyHookHandler", 
            MB_YESNOCANCEL);
    }


    assert(result == IDYES || result == IDNO || result == IDCANCEL);
    return result;
}

#pragma endregion
```

Is it possible to monitor all file operations in the monitored directory, which is in this case C:\Users\User\CloudRAID?

Comment: The docs say "A copy hook handler ... determines if a Shell folder or printer object can be moved, copied, renamed, or deleted". So it seems to work only on folders and printers. If you want to be notified about file changes, you should consider [change notification handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx). But those don't let you cancel the operation, they just notify you.

Comment: @KarstenKoop yeah I thought that by using the CopyCallback it will also include all the files inside the folder so that I could create a restriction of some file operations in certain folder